# Finding Arc In image using python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have this image, I want to find arc's in the image, i have tried HoughCircles but it finds complete circles, not the circle that is 1/4th forth which i am calling arc, using contours and Momentum also doesnt helps as it find every dot as separate contour.

Here is my image, i have found everything else using many different algorithms, even got the windows, i just want to find doors.. any clue ..
[image]

Comment: Since there are only 4 kind of arcs, and they are always equal and axis aligned (at least for this image), template matching could work just ok.

Comment: yes i know, i have used that technique but that is only for this specific image, i want rotation and size invariant.. in other image the size will vary.. though i have also used surf detection but problem with that is, there aren't that many features in image to detect..

Comment: So, please provide a few other images. And yes, SURF or other local descriptors won't work in this case (lack of texture).